# label is not show at proper position at xAxis with dattime type into highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

My xAxis configuration is :

> {
>
> ```
> labels:{
>          enabled:true,
>          style:{
>            fontSize:'9Px',width: '175px'
>          },
>         formatter: function () {
>            var s = "";
>            s = s + getWeekDates(this.value);
>            s = s + "," + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.value);
>            return s;
>            }
> }
> ```
>
> type: 'datetime',
>
> minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000 *7,
>
> }

But when i hover on chart, tickLabel and marker is not at same position!!

[image][image]

I want that when i hover on `w5,2014 label`, marker must be at vertical position. 
Thank you in advance..

Comment: Can you provide a live demo like jsfiddle?

Comment: Please refer this one : http://jsfiddle.net/o2k8b517/ . In this , hover on chart, and you can see that tooltip data and label data is not same!!

Answer (score 0):

You should set [pointRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.column.pointRange) and then adapt tickInterval.